# Why is my C code in line 29 executing before the three for loops above it?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to make a Mario block simulator that symmetrically places blocks, the code works but when i execute it there is an empty row between "Number between 1 and 8: " and the start of the blocks.

```
 Number between 1 and 8: 8

        #  #
       ##  ##
      ###  ###
     ####  ####
    #####  #####
   ######  ######
  #######  #######
 ########  ########
```

I've tried commenting out other code but its the `printf("\n");` in line 29 that is responsible and I don't understand why it's ran before other code...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

    {

        for (int i = 0;i < 8; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 8; j != i; j--)
                    {
                         printf(" ");
                    }
                for(int j = 0; j != i; j++)
                    {
                        printf("#");
                    }

                printf("  ");

                for(int j = 0; j != i; j++)
                    {
                        printf("#");
                }
                printf("\n");

            }
    }
```

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and/or add debug print messages to follow the execution flow.

Comment: This loop: `for(int j = 0; j > 0; j++)` doesn't look like it will *ever* print a newline.

Comment: Can you please make your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i've minimized the code a bit and fixed the loop i was playing around with but there still is that one empty line

Comment: How many `#` do you think are printed on a line when `i` is zero?

Comment: Wow, it was right under my nose, thank you Eric.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

    {

        for (int i = 1;i < 8; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 8; j != i; j--)
                    {
                         printf(" ");
                    }
                for(int j = 0; j != i; j++)
                    {
                        printf("#");
                    }

                printf("  ");

                for(int j = 0; j != i; j++)
                    {
                        printf("#");
                }
                printf("\n");

            }
    }
```